# SugarCRM variables email template not working

Tags: email, templates, variables, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I've searching information about it. And i found that a lot of people had the same problem.

I've registered this guy as a lead. Then i try, to send a email with a template where using variables include his name into the mail.

As you can see is created as lead:
[image]

You can see i'm using lead variables:
[image]

And in the mail variables aren't substituted for the lead name.

What can i do?

Edit: I'm using version 7.8.3 of SugarCRM.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue recently but with PDF templates, I changed the lead to leads, generally speaking, I switched to the plural module name.

Lead -> leads
Opportunity -> Opportunities

and so on. Give it a try